# Intellij Idea slow compile Android app

Tags: android, compilation, intellij-idea

I try working with Android applications in Eclipse and Intellij Idea. All work ok, but in Intellij Idea I get very slow compiling of Android application (in Eclipse more fast). Most of time pick up this process:

```
Generating classes.dex
```

There is any variants to accelerate building android package in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80408 and wait for it to fixed...

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you don't have some large extra library added to the dependencies by mistake. If target APK size is similar in Eclipse and IDEA, provide a sample project to reproduce this slow compilation problem.